# How to solve the problem of not being able to type code in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I cannot type or edit code in Pycharm as there is a black mark (shown in image) instead of normal horizontal line that is normally visible when you type. Please let me know how I could solve this issue. Thank you.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLqTz.png)

Comment: can you add a picture of what you mean?

Comment: _black mark (shown in image)_ what image? Please edit your question to include your screenshot.

Comment: Yatish and Miles- sorry, just figured out how to add the image. Should be visible now.

Comment: try this link https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206159619-How-do-I-change-cursor-from-a-block-back-to-

Comment: Thank you, that worked. The issue was to do with "Toggle Insert/Ovewrite" option in Editor Actions within Keymap in Settings. The mode was originally assigned when I pressed the insert key by accident, so pressing it again brought the normal cursor back. I am new to this website, can I rate your reply somehow?